# Is it possible to optically threshold the amplitude of light waves - lower amplitude passes unaffected, higher amplitude gets lowered?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

One can certainly create a digital circuit the achieves this - is it possible to do it in a purely "optical" manner?

If not with light waves, would it be possible with any other type of wave?

Low amplitude wave remains unaffected
[image: low amplitude wave passes unaffected]

High amplitude wave gets its amplitude lowered
[image: high amplitude wave gets its amplitude lowered]

Answer (score 3):

1. [Non-linear optical media](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics)

e.g. a media that generates double frequency light will pass low intensity light but convert a greater geal of high-intensity light into something else

2. the light may change the media physically (e.g. heating) or chemically (e.g. light-sensitive glasses that get black when irradiated make very handy goggles)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance - the wikipedia page seems to show how we can increase the frequency of an incoming wave, or how to boost the amplitude of an incoming wave. It doesn't seem to have anything on the topic of letting low amplitude light passing, but reducing the higher amplitude light.

Comment: Could you point me to something more specific perhaps? Thanks :)

Comment: @Pragy It is not very easy to come up with a nonlinear process with the characteristics you've described. But fraxinus's point is correct: in any linear optical system (meaning, the overwhelming majority of optical systems) the transmissivity is independent of intensity, and the property you want is impossible. What you are asking for intrinsically requires nonlinear optics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photochromic_lens

Comment: Example of 2: A high power CO$_2$ laser is sometimes focused to a spot for welding or cutting. If the lens absorbs too much, it will get hot, expand, and change focal length a little. The focal spot grows, and the intensity in it drops. The cutter doesn't work as well.